# Processing Lag causes weird distorted images to appear

Tags: processing, lag

so I made this processing program

```java
void setup() {
  size(5000, 5000);
}
```

When I ran it, it caused terrible lag but the important part is on the window appeared distorted images of a youtube video i was watching, and many other things i've been using my computer for. I am not sure how it works, and I would appreciate if someone explained why it happened.

NOTE : this is processing 3 i'm using

Comment: I've been trying to add commands after the size like "background(0, 255, 0);" but it doesn't make a diffrence

Comment: Also to minimize lag try restarting your computer before attempting to replicate it

Answer (score 0):

That code runs fine on my computer.

This sounds like a problem with your graphics card, not Processing. Try updating all of your drivers and restarting your computer. If that doesn't fix the problem, you might be looking at a hardware problem.

What happens if you try a smaller window?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. I just want to know why. I'm curios!